# Select days from day where active=1, If active=0, do nothing

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have table with days, version and active.

In table I have  the same days where active = 1 and active = 0
I need to get from the database all these days, where active = 1 and where version_id is max.
For this purpose I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT 'MAX(version_id)',DAY, active FROM `day` group by day, active
```

But days 28 and 29 are duplicated so when I use "AND active = 0" then it shows me days 28 with active = 1 (and lower MAX(VERSION_ID) but that day should not be seen.

Query result: http://screenshooter.net/0562655/27_05_2012__09_02_56

So:
"SHOW ME ALL DAYS WHERE VERSION_ID IS MAX AND DAY IS ACTIVE, if active = 0, do not show an earlier version"

Comment: Can you try `SELECT 'MAX(version_id)', DAY FROM day where active=1 group by day;`

Comment: @anubhava, http://screenshooter.net/0562655/27_05_2012__09_29_13
it gives me 28 with max 16562, but MAX is 16563

Comment: 16563 is for active=0 not for active=1. You wrote `SHOW ME ALL DAYS WHERE VERSION_ID IS MAX AND DAY IS ACTIVE` does it not mean retrieve max(version_id) for active=1. If not can you list your expected data in your question please.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it with a nested query:

```
SELECT * FROM `day`
WHERE `active` = 1 AND version_id = (
    SELECT MAX(version_id) FROM `day`
)
```

Comment: Ok, but it gives me only one day, and i need to get all days

Comment: Maybe because there is only one day matching the criteria?

Comment: Nope, for each day is max(version_id), your query shows max(version_id) for all table not all days

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT * 
FROM day
WHERE version_id IN (SELECT MAX(d.version_id) 
                    FROM day d
                    WHERE active = 1
                    GROUP BY d.day)
OR active = 0
```

Comment: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Corrected the answer. Can you try now.

Comment: your query returns all the days, I need those for which max (version_id) and active = 0
Keep in mind that in the table is another column "employees", so the exact query should be:
"Display days where day=max(day) and active=0, group by employee, date"

Comment: You have not mentioned anything bout employees in ur question.

Comment: Added the active part as well. Can check the query?